# Google Sheet script to import range a folder to one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was researching how to do what I needed and I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZtb3lRWn74) and thought it was PERFECT for me.

It shows how to set up a script on a page to import an entire folder, which is exactly what I need. I have 14 sheets that are identical. I need to copy `A2:F` from all of them into one sheet. Here is the script:

```
function getdata() {
    var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B94fkeHjleasRF9QMDFlcHllRVU").getFiles()
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());

      var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A2:F');
      var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();

      var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
      var destrange = destsheet.getRange('A2:F'); 
      destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);         
   }
 }
```

The problem is: although it worked in the video, I can't seem to get it to work for me. I played with the last line (which where I am getting an error). I managed to get the script to delete all the information I needed to copy. Lol. So obviously I need help. Can anyone see any glaring mistakes in this script?

I have tried `importRange` but it hangs up on array formulas. This script seemed perfect, if only I could get it to work.

Comment: Currently, your code is getting the same values from the active sheet on every `while` loop.  If you want the source data to be the data from the active sheet, and it's always the same range, you should put that outside of the loop.  You'd only need to get the source data once.

Comment: I have only done a few scripts. and I am afraid I dont understand what you are saying? I do see I messed up on the A2,F and changed that to 2,6. But that did not work either

Comment: There are 4 different variations of the `getRange()` method.  Each takes either a different number of parameters, or a different type of parameter.  I'm using a different variation in the code I'm proposing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

- Gets files from a specific folder
- Loops through all the files in the folder
- Tests for the Mime Type of the file to get only spreadsheets
- Gets all the values out of the source sheet tab
- Writes all new data to the end of existing data

For this code to work, you must enter your folder ID, your source sheet tab name, and the destination spreadsheet file ID.

Code:

```
function getdata() {
  //declare multiple variables in one statement - Initial value will
  //be undefined
  var destinationSpreadsheet,destinationSS_ID,destsheet,destrange,file,files,
      sourcerange,sourceSS,sourcesheet,srcSheetName,sourcevalues;

  srcSheetName = "Type the Name of Source Sheet Tab Here";
  destinationSS_ID = "Type the Name of destination spreadsheet file ID Here";
  files = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder ID").getFiles();
  destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSS_ID);
  destsheet = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    if (file.getMimeType() !== "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet") {
      continue;
    };
    sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    sourcesheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
    //sourcesheet.getRange(start row, start column, numRows, number of Columns)
    sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange(2,1,sourcesheet.getLastRow()-1,6);
    sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();

    //Write all the new data to the end of this data
    destrange = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
        .getRange(destsheet.getLastRow()+1,1,sourcevalues.length,sourcevalues[0].length);

    destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);         
  };
};
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 7, file "Import") Still getting an error message. I know we are close.. but no cigar.

Comment: See update to answer.  There are two methods, when only one is needed.

Comment: Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number). (line 7, file "Import")    I did have to replace the getsheetbyname with getactive()). But I am still getting an error on the sourcerange line

Comment: Sandy I got the script to work!!! But . It deletes everything in the folders. And does not copy them to the destination file. I am not sure where they go? So not yet. Any other suggestions from anyone?

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that deletes files.  Mark this answer as correct, and if you have another section of code that is deleting files, ask another question and add that code.

Comment: this is honestly the entire code and the ONLY code. I am not sure why it is deleting the files. It might be moving the files. but it is NOT putting them on the page it is supposed to.

Comment: Most of the methods are **get**Something.  Nothing can get deleted or overwritten with a **get** method.  The only **set** method is the `setValues()` method, and that writes values to a sheet tab.  It would never delete a file.  So, I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: The code is doing the opposite of what you want.  The target or destination sheet needs to be outside of the `while` loop.  There are multiple source sheets, that need to be inside of the loop.  See updated answer.

Comment: I just made some more changes.  My first update wasn't correct.  Hopefully this is more correct.

Comment: Hi Sandy - I know this was (painfully) solved in comments, but comments are not permanent. Could you put the key points of the problem & solution into your answer, for future readers?

Comment: I am receiving the same error "TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 14, file "Code")" but I don't see any solution mentioned here. @Connie can you share how you overcame this?

Comment: Did you change the name of `Sheet1` to the name of the sheet tab that you are using?  See updated code.  Did you enter the correct folder ID?